# Why do we assign `(keyup)` to random value for template local variables to get updated in Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

If I want `#box` to get updated in `<p>` I need to assign `(keyup)` to some random value

For example

```
  <!-- It doesn't matter what value I put on the right of equality sign for (keyup) -->
  <input #box (keyup)="some_random_value" placeholder="something">
  <p>{{box.value}}</p>
```

If for example I have

```
  <input #box placeholder="something">
  <p>{{box.value}}</p>
```

`#box` doesn't get updated at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained about halfway through the [User Input section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html) of the official docs (search for (keyup)="0"). Angular2, in an attempt to improve performance, only runs changes detection when a UI event happens if it knows that you did something - anything - in response to the event. Having a binding for the event qualifies even if that binding doesn't actually do anything.